# How to help so I can improve on my documentation and reapply

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, ghanaian-citizens

[image]

I am a Ghanaian male. A 3rd year non working Medical student in the carribean but a registered Pharmacist in my home country. But currently in the carribean. I was refused a standard visitors visa for which I wanted to visit the Uk for 3weeks for vacation and return to school. I would like to reapply this December for vacation. I would really appreciate any recommendations and criticisms as to what I have to do in order to increase my chances of getting the visa. Thank you.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie While there are a lot of questions & answers dealing with the interpretation of UK visa refusal letters on this site, the specific one you've picked as a duplicate seems to have too many individualities to be a good match.

Comment: @Ernest Some suggestions to consider: 1 Premise for your visit - why the U.K.? Why now? The premise should be coherent and make sense in the context of your age, lifestyle, profession, social standing and so on. 2 Returnability: What will compel you to leave at the end of your visit? Proof of family ties will help. If you are not a permanent resident in the country where you are submitting your application, you will need to prove that you can exit the UK to your residence without any problems. 3. Finances: is the amount you plan to spend reasonable given your lifestyle, do you have savings?